# SQL invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: oracle, ddl

Calendar

```
CREATE TABLE CALENDAR
(
    CalendarKey int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Date DATE DEFAULT (SYSDATE), 
    DayofWeek VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
    DayofMonth VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    DayofYear VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    WeekofMonth VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    WeekofYear VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    Month MONTH DEFAULT (SYSMONTH),
    Year YEAR DEFAULT (SYSYEAR)
);
```

This code causes an error:

[image]

> Error report -
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Don't see any error, please help.

Comment: There is no `sysmonth` or `sysyear` in Oracle. Where [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/index.html) did you find that?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, why separate columns for 'month' and 'year'?  That's sure to cause problems down the road.  Just use a single column of type DATE.  If all you care about is the month and year, you can just use TRUNC when you query the column, to ignore the day and time parts of DATE.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> create table calendar
  2    (calendarkey int constraint pk_cal primary key,
  3     datum       date default (sysdate),
  4     dayofweek   varchar2(50) not null,
  5     dayofmonth  varchar2(50) not null,
  6     dayofyear   varchar2(50) not null,
  7     weekofmonth varchar2(50) not null,
  8     weekofyear  varchar2(50) not null,
  9     month       number(2) default extract (month from sysdate),
 10     year        number(4) default extract (year  from sysdate)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

So, what did you do wrong (along with additional notes):

- you can't name a column `date` as it is reserved for datatype name (actually, you *could*, but you *should not* - by enclosing its name into double quotes)
- primary key implies that the column can't contain NULL values, so - no need to specify `NOT NULL`. Also, it is a good habit to name all constraints
- there aren't `sysmonth` nor `sysyear` in Oracle, but - if I got it right - you can use `sysdate` and extract those values (month and year) from it
- do you *really* need 50 characters to store *days and weeks*? Not that you're charged on column size, but ... which day occupies up to 50 characters?

Comment: Thank you for the information and knowledge, well fair enough there's no such days or weeks which requires 50 characters.. just thought having more is better than having less since processing power is not going to be calculated, probably a good thing to change such mindset.